# MySQL Delete many rows where the values are the same

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know if there is a query that could delete all the rows where id is 1

I try this query but i got an error

```
DELETE * FROM Contributions WHERE ID=1
```

---

```
receipt | id | date | amount
0001    | 1  | 2020 | 100
0002    | 1  | 2019 | 12
0003    | 2  | 2019 | 130
0004    | 1  | 2019 | 20
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Before asking any question make sure to do some research about the issue by yourself. It is a simple delete command you can google it easily.

Comment: Please go through this website: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/
It has plenty of well versed topics and resources

Answer (score 2):

Remove `*` from your query and try the following. Here is more details on [delete](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/mysql/how-to-delete-in-mysql).

```
DELETE FROM Contributions WHERE ID=1
```

Comment: I tried it but it delete just 1 row